# How to schedule a task to be run in the morning but only once a day?

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I need to disable Aero on Windows 7 but I need to do it only once a day. And then enable Aero once the system is started and my GPU is calm ;-).

Note that I need it to work also after waking up from hibernation, but preferable not run after each lock.

P.S.: In case you are wondering - yes, I do have AMD GPU which is failing with BSOD when Aero is on :-/. And, no - nothing really helps but disabling Aero at startup.

**Edit**: Note that I know how to stop/start Aero (`sc start/stop uxsms`). I don't know how to make a schedule that makes sure the start task will get called e.g. 30 minutes after stop task. And stop task should get called on the first startup of the computer (no matter if it is a plain startup or waking up from hibernation).

Comment: To clarify, you need one to run on startup and the other to run 30 minutes later, regardless of when startup occurs?  (I.e. if you rebooted at some point during the day, you'd need the same thing to happen?)

Comment: I wouldn't mind if it would happen after restart but I would prefer it would happen once a day. And it need to happen in a sequence - stop Aero at startup (or login) and after 30 minutes start Aero.

Answer (score 1):

OK. So I made something that works for me but your mileage may vary ;-).

I have had a couple of triggers (not sure about their English names though):

- At login - which actually is not at every login but at login after restart (sadly doesn't work after hibernation).
- Every day at 5 - which coupled with Run fast if omitted should work also after hibernation... But doesn't. Not for me at least.
- After event - and this works great, but probably only in my case (display driver failure). The log is "System", source "Display", Event id "4101".

And just in case that don't work in some case for you you can make a shortcut to whatever task. The target of the shortcut should be:

```
schtasks.exe /run /TN "Folder\Task name"
```

I could also probably make a service (a simple exe working in the background as a service) that would wake up at each day and push something to event log or just run the task, but above works for me.

Oh and since "After event" works for me I have another task that starts Aero 30 minutes after that event (just added delay on the trigger edit dialog).